# My Chrome's "Add to Reading List" button disappeared overnight - how can I get it back?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, reading-list

A few months ago, Google Chrome updated the "Add Bookmark" button (inside the right side of the address bar) so that clicking it will show a menu with two choices: Add as a normal bookmark, or add to Chrome's reading-list:

[image]

However since yesterday, my Chrome browser doesn't show the "Add to Reading List" option anymore: clicking the Star button brings-up the "Bookmark Added!" dialog:

[image]

Initially I was anxious that Google had just killed-off The Reading List itself (just like [so many other nice things](https://killedbygoogle.com/)), but I saw that the Reading List is still there in my Bookmarks Bar with my previously saved pages, so at least nothing's gone... except the ability to add pages to the Reading List.

[image]

...though curiously, the "Add current tab" button appears in the Reading List, but the Bookmarks Bar only appears in the Chrome New Tab page, which cannot be added to the Reading List anyway - and the Reading List doesn't appear anywhere inside the Bookmarks Manager either - so it's not possible at all for me to add pages to it.

Comment: It was an experiment by Google. You can toggle a flag for it in chrome://flags, but it doesn't show up. Seems like they removed the feature completely. Best luck getting your bookmarks back. I didn't figure it out yet.

Comment: Oh, it has been moved to side panel. https://9to5google.com/2022/04/01/how-to-the-side-panel-to-manage-bookmarks-in-google-chrome/